# How to clear multiple textviews upon Editing?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am trying to clear multiple textviews on editing. I know how do so with one textView (IE):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTextView.delegate = self
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    myTextView.text = ""
}
```

How would I use the same concept for multiple textviews?

Comment: do you want to clear the text in all text views when one text views starts editing ?

Comment: I wish to change only the one being edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    myTextView.text = ""
}
```

The above delegate method will get called when a text view begins editing. And this method holds the reference to the `textView` that called in the `textView` object. You can use that reference to clear the text instead of using a separate reference/outlet to the `textView`.

So the method would be:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    textView.text = ""
}
```

**From the Documentation:**

Description:

> Tells the delegate that editing began in the specified text field.
>   This method notifies the delegate that the specified text field just
>   became the first responder. Use this method to update state
>   information or perform other tasks. For example, you might use this
>   method to show overlay views that are visible only while editing.
>   Implementation of this method by the delegate is optional.

Parameters:

**textView**

> The text view in which an editing session began.